# Why sealed modifier cannot be used with object in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

Why `sealed class User` compiles successfully but `sealed object User` throws a compilation error?

I went through Kotlin docs but got nothing. I am playing a bit with Kotlin and just wanted to know the reason behind this?

Comment: `sealed` has a different meaning in Kotlin than in other languages; it denotes something like an enumerated type and does _not_ mean the same as `final`. (in short, as already described, `sealed object` doesn't make any sense)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sealed` classes are supposed to be open, however all objects are `final`: `sealed` classes have a certain quantity of subclasses (inside the file, where the sealed class is declared), but objects are singletons, so they cannot have any subclasses. Consequently, `sealed object` declaration does not make any sense and can't be compiled.